# Invoke function of same name in all children from a parent

Tags: php

I have a class A with a function func().

I have 3 classes B, C, D that extend A.

A::func() should call B::func(), C::func()...

I'd like to use static functions because I won't need to instantiate every children.

I think A should be abstract (I'd like it to be).

How can I do this in PHP ?

Comment: `A::func()` should call `B::func()`, `C::func()...` that doesn't make sense: the parent class depends on its child classes? I mean, if `A::func()` should call `B::func()`, why not make `A::func` an abstract method and call `B::func` directly?

Comment: Just to be sure, you want B to extend A, and C to extend A. But you want A to call a function of B (and C) ? It seems to be a bad design but maybe there is a mistake somewhere. The parent class should not know about its children.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking to do, but by the looks of things you'd be better off using traits.

Comment: So far it sounds like a design flaw. Please describe what you're trying to achive, not how.

Comment: @Andrew: trying to fix a design fault using something like traits is trying to turn 2 negatives into a positive. It won't work, it'll end in tears. Besides [Traits are evil](https://eliasvo.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/php-traits-if-they-werent-evil-theyd-be-funny/), for [a lot of reasons](https://eval.in/429208)

Comment: I want to have a parent class launching Events. These events will be called by classes launching GTMEvents for example, or Google analytics events, etc. I'd like to have one single call for every subevent to launch instead of calling every single child individually every time an event is sent.

Comment: @user3807702: Please learn about [Dependency Injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/what-is-dependency-injection.html), that's the best way to implement event handling in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Declare it [abstract](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) but once you make the function static you cannot test it (PHPUnit), you cannot mock static methods.

```
abstract class C
{
    static function func()
    {
        echo 'base';
    }
}
abstract class B extends C
{
    static function func()
    {
        parent::func();
        echo 'B';
    }
}
class A extends B
{
    static function func()
    {
        parent::func();
        echo 'A';
    }
}
A::func(); //Displays: baseBA
```

Comment: But calling A::func() will only call func() from A. I'd like A::func() to call B::func() AND C::func()...

Comment: A::func() to call B::func() and C::func() at the same time or A::func() call B::func() call C::func()?

Comment: It should call these two at the same time. B::func() and C::func() aren't linked in any other way than function name and A.

Answer (score -1):

I've finally done it like this :

```
final class A
{
    public static function call($sFunctionName) {
        $aClasses = ['B', 'C'];

        foreach ($aClasses as $sClassName) {
            if (method_exists($sClassName, $sFunctionName)) {
                call_user_func($sClassName.'::'.$sFunctionName);
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Is this still bad design ? The array of classes is actually defined in an external config file.

Comment: Yes, this is still bad design. Al you check is if _a_ class with name `A` and method name `$sFunctionName` (a user-supplied argument) exists. What parameters this method expects, and whether or not it is static is not ensured. IF you need a class to call a method defined on another class ***inject that dependency*** It's not hard to do. What you're doing now is really too close to `eval` for comfort: read an external file (Strings), and concatenating an un-santized value onto a string. What if I added `DateTime` or `PDO` to the external file, and then called `A::call('__construct')`

Comment: I know about dependency injection but I can't seem to find how I could use it practically here since I need to call the same method name on multiple classes.

Comment: Oops, -1 ! There I go for asking criticism !

Comment: For the record: the -1 wasn't mine. I don't down-vote without explaining why. I'm only trying to explain that what you're doing now is bad form. It reeks of bad design. Go back, ask yourself what it is you really need, and think about alternative ways of achieving your goals, because trust me when I say there are many, many valid alternatives

Comment: I'm 100% sure it wasn't you since you took time to help me and wrote a big explanation :) I'm gonna try to find how I can do what I want in a better fashion, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do something like this:

```
abstract class A
{
    protected static function func()
    {
        echo 'base';
    }

    public static function extFunc()
    {
        static::func();
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    protected static function func()
    {
        parent::func();
        echo 'B';
    }
}
class C extends A
{
    protected static function func()
    {
        parent::func();
        echo 'C';
    }
}
C::extFunc(); //Displays: baseC
```

where you have a public method which calls a protected method from within.